# How I can add a "roles" to a "path" dynamically in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, yii2, acl, rbac

In SF2 I have the following scenario, according to the site itself documentation:

## app\config\security.yml

```
security:
    access_control:
         - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
         - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I need to manually add each "path" and "roles" that can access this "path".
How can I do this dynamically?
Like RBAC on Yii2:

[image]

Is there any ready Bundle or something in SF2 own documentation that allows this? As the hypothetical example:

## app\config\security.yml

```
security:
    access_control:
         type: dynamically
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make adding the roles easier you can use [annotations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/securing_services.html#securing-methods-using-annotations).

Your question asks for dynamic security, which is complicated. The routes, and all roles, are compiled during the cache warmup phase. So, for this to work you'll first need to store your dynamic values. The database would be a good option for this. Here I am only going to show how to check the roles, the actual role manipulation I'll leave to you.

The easiest method is to inject the authorization checker into your controller.

```
services:
    acme_controller:
        class:     "AcmeDemoBundle\Controller"
        arguments: ["@security.authorization_checker"]
```

Then check the roles in the action(s):

```
public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker)
{
    $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
}

public function listAction()
{
    $role = /* load your role here */;
    if (false === $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted($role)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    // ...
}
```

The above will cause duplicated code if you want it in many controllers, so you could also create a [voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html):

```
services:
    acme.route.voter:
        class: AcmeDemoBundle\RouteVoter
        arguments:
            - @security.role_hierarchy
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: security.voter, priority: 300 }
```

Example:

```
public function __construct ( RoleHierarchyInterface $roleHierarchy )
{
    $this->roleVoter   = new RoleHierarchyVoter( $roleHierarchy );
}

public function vote ( TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes )
{
    if ( !$object instanceof Request ) {
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }

    $requestUri = $object->getPathInfo();

    if ( isset($this->votes[ $requestUri ]) ) {
        return $this->votes[ $requestUri ];
    }

    $roles = /* load your roles */;

    return $this->votes[ $requestUri ] = $this->roleVoter->vote( $token, $object, $roles );
}
```

Another method would be to replace the `router` service with your own implementation. This is the approach taken my the [CMF Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/routing/dynamic.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can manage role/route relation dynamically like this :

You create a listener on the kernel

```
<service id="toto.security.controller_listener" class="Administration\SecurityBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener">
    <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.controller" method="onKernelController" />
    <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
</service>
```

and after in the listener you implement this method

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
      $controller = $event->getController();
      if (!is_array($controller)) {
        return;
      }



        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $baseUrl = $request->getBaseUrl();
        $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri();
        $route = str_replace($baseUrl, "", $requestUri);
        //you put your check logic
        //you can implement a relation beetween routes  and roles/ users in database etc. you got the entire control on what you do
        if(!$this->accessMananager->isGrantAccess(User $user, $route)){
           throw new AccessDeniedException("blah blah blah")
        }


}
```

since this listener will always be called before any of your controller, consider creating a cache system